# Deleting Specific Substrings in Strings [Swift]

Tags: swift, string

I have a string `var m = "I random don't like confusing random code."` I want to delete all instances of the substring `random` within string `m`, returning string `parsed` with the deletions completed.

The end result would be: `parsed = "I don't like confusing code."`

How would I go about doing this in Swift 3.0+?

Comment: var m = "I random don't like confusing random code." 
    let parsed = m.replacingOccurrences(of: "random", with: "")
    print(parsed). // I  don't like confusing  code.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

It is quite simple enough, there is one of many ways where you can replace the string "random" with empty string

```
let parsed = m.replacingOccurrences(of: "random", with: "")
```

Answer (score 13):

Depend on how complex you want the replacement to be (remove/keep punctuation marks after `random`). If you want to remove `random` and optionally the space behind it:

```
var m = "I random don't like confusing random code."
m = m.replacingOccurrences(of: "random ?", with: "", options: [.caseInsensitive, .regularExpression])
```

Comment: @Harmish thanks a previous version in my playground had other punctuation marks hence the grouping